# pkill not working in system() command

Tags: c++, linux, system, pkill

I am trying to kill a process in a C++ program (Linux).
I know exactly the name of the program to kill. If I try in Bash

```
pkill process-name
```

the process is killed normally.

If in a simple C++ program I run in `main`

```
system("pkill process-name")
```

the process continues to run.

I have no idea why...

Comment: Does `process-name` contain something 'weird', e.g. regex?

Comment: its called mtc-serial-communication

Comment: What is the exit code of `system()`?

Comment: does your c++ program have the right permission to kill the other process? Have you tried running your program with sudo and see if it works?

Comment: @KhouriGiordano the exit code is 256

Comment: You can consider the return of `system()` the same as `waitpid()` and use macros to break it down: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html

Comment: @EhsanEnayati The program is launched on a board wich runs a linux distribution made with the yocto project, and doesn't needs sudo to get rights

Comment: @KhouriGiordano Sorry, what you mean with "use macros to break it down?" can you give me more details as an answer please?

Comment: @Talkanian `if (WIFEXITED(val)) printf("exit code: %d\n",WEXITSTATUS(val));` There's also a test for signaled i.e. crashes.